# aws cloudformation jenkins plugin not taking parameters from the build in Cloud Formation recipe file/S3 URL field

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-cloudformation

I am using the [aws cloudformation jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Cloudformation+Plugin) plugin to create stack. My job has a parameter named `S3URL`. The screenshot is attached below

[image: S3URL Parameter in Jenkins]

Now I am passing the `S3URL` in the [cloud formation plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Cloudformation+Plugin) as follows

[image: Cloud Formation Plugin Screenshot]

When I run the Job, I get the following `error` message in the job logs

[image]

It seems that the `S3URL` parameter value is not getting inputted into the [aws cloudformation jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Cloudformation+Plugin). Can somebody tell me as to what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I am passing a valid S3 url during the build in the parameters as a string.

Answer (score 0):

@shubhamagiwal92 I was also getting same issue.

I was unable to use environment variable in "Parameters" section of "Create stack" job configuration.

So instead, I've used the following steps:

1. I've set the value of S3URL, KeyName and other parameters in environment variable by using command the following command:

> export S3URL=s3://url/

2. I've used aws-cli to pass these parameter values using an "Execute Shell" step, like so:

> aws cloudformation deploy --template-file $S3URL --stack-name MyStack
> --parameter-overrides KeyName=$KEYNAME

Comment: Edit your answer please.